# How to display the result as a vertical list for this code?

Tags: php, mysql, html

My code is as shown.But the results are displayed as a horizontal list like this :

Questions selected
    Explain how to produce the vector image, List THREE of image file types or formats used in multimedia, construct a diagram

```
$a= array(implode(", ", $_GET["choice"]));
echo "<table align=\"center\">";
echo "<tr><th>Questions selected </th></tr>";



while (list ($key, $val) = each ($a)) { 
echo"<tr><td>";
echo " $val "; 
echo "</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

I want them to be displayed like this :

```
Questions selected :
Explain how to produce the vector image
List THREE of image file types or formats used in multimedia
```

So how can i list them 1 by 1 vertically ?Can somebody help me please ?I have tried putting them in table but i'm still getting them display horizontally.

Comment: Have you tried just adding a `<br />` tag after every $val without any tables ?

Comment: it's the same.because the val is a list of items.How to grab them out 1 by 1 ?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct.. What browser you are using? Use Firebug in FireFox to inspect the element, that what is actually being rendered on the screen.

Comment: no,i did not remove the while.i remove the table elements only if i place the br.but it's still horizontally displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You build $a as an array containing only one string. This is why it shows only one line.

implode takes and array, and join each item. If you want to separate a string into an array, you need to use explode.

Try with simply:

```
$a = $_GET["choice"];
```

Comment: Can you show me how to separate them ? I'm not good at array.Please help me

Comment: Could you give an example of what $_GET["choice"] looks like?

Comment: 'GET["choice"]' is a list of questions that is being selected from check box. Multiple selections.

Comment: just `print $_GET["choice"]` and let me know what is it printing.